# change $0.684 210 526 3$ into a fraction

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

I am a non-mathematician who quit with math after middle school. Now I face a practical problem which I cannot solve.

Suppose I want to turn $0.684 210 526 3$ into a fraction, how would I do that withou using my `convert to fraction button on my calculator'. To use other words, are there two number $a$ and $b$ less than $20$ such that 
$\frac{a}{b}=0.684 210 526 3?$

Thank you in advance,

Mary

Comment: The problem is your calculator doesn't tell you if that number is the exact answer or an approximation - if the answer is 0.6842105263 or if it is actually something like 0.6842105263...

Comment: Extremely close is $\frac{13}{19}$.

Comment: Try multiplying  $0.6842105263$ by each number between $1$ and $20$, excluding those which obviously will not produce anything close to an integer result. (So probably good to start at the top end, excluding $20$)

Comment: Overkill, but I used continued fractions. It is not hard to describe the procedure at a blackboard, but hard to type.

Comment: @andre exactly my thought, it is [0, 1, 2, 6, 175438596, 3] for this example, the fifth convergent is very large, so [0,1,2,6], which is the continued fraction of $\frac{13}{19}$ is a very good approximation.

Comment: @mary Welcome to math stack exchange! I hope you enjoy this site!

Comment: @andre what do you think about my try below ?

Comment: There may not be enough detail for someone who has been away from mathematics for quite a while.

Comment: OK, I deleted it.

Comment: @Peter: Just saw this (it was not pinged to me). Do not delete, with a few additional lines it may be useful to OP.

Answer (score 5):

When you want to convert any decimal into a fraction, follow these steps:

1. Put the decimal over 1 i.e. $\frac{\text{decimal}}{1}$
2. Then multiply the top and bottom by 10 until all the decimals are gone.
3. Try to reduce the problem

So, in this case we have: $0.684 210 526 3$ and which as 10 decimals places so we will have:

$$\frac{0.684 210 526 3}{1}$$

then

$$\frac{684 210 526 3}{10000000000}$$

Now the question is, can we reduce it? The answer is no. Since, the only numbers that can divide denominator are either $2,5$ or a multiple of $5$ (there are other divisors i.e. $4,8,16 \ldots 1024$). This also has to be the case for the numerator but it isn't so, the problem cannot be reduced further. If you want an approximation for the decimal then as the other answer has suggested, $\frac{13}{19}$ is pretty good according to [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.6842105263).

Comment: Nitpick: your description of the divisors of the denominator is off by several powers of two.

Comment: @ErickWong Sorry, slightly confused what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, it was a slightly cheeky way of saying that there are other divisors besides the ones you described, namely $4, 8, 16, \ldots, 1024$ (none of which are $2$, $5$, or multiples of $5$).

Comment: Ahh right, I'll fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Write the digits on the top and 1 followed by the same number of zeroes as you have digits on the bottom:
$$
0.23 = \frac{23}{100}
$$
and for you
$$
0.6842105263 = \frac{6842105263}{10000000000}
$$

To find if there is a simple fraction which indeed resembles yours (in other words, if the output of the calculator is an approximation and you are looking for something reasonably close to it) -- Wolfram Alpha does a very decent job at such things.

[Your input](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.6842105263%20) gives 13/19, for example.

Comment: @JonathanY. reread it -- added a numerical methodology for that as well

Comment: Aha! (I didn't know Alpha does that, although I shouldn't be surprised. Still, the type of exact analysis @gekkostate performed seems appropriate to me.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a try to make the continued fraction clearer (see comment above)

$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{6}}}$$ is the fraction giving the approximation. Begin at the bottom at $2+\frac{1}{6}$ and work up to the top.

Here is how you get the numbers 1,2,6 :

Begin with x, calculate 1/x and subtract the number before the comma. Continue this
process.

Comment: Peter, perhaps if you'd mention here that this answer continues the comments above w.r.t continued fructions, and link to a more exhaustive review of the subject?

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, your specific question does not reduce to an exact fraction whose numerator and denominator are less than twenty.

To address the general question, most software and hardware implementations convert decimal numbers to fractions by traversing (as a type of binary search) over the [Stern-Brocot tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern_Brocot_tree) until either an exact or approximate match (to some specified precision) is found.

The general procedure is as follows:

1) Given a positive decimal input $x$ and precision $p$, let $a$ and $b$ be fractions representing the boundaries of the search with initial values $a \leftarrow \frac{0}{1}, b \leftarrow \frac{1}{0}$.

2) Calculate the [mediant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_%28mathematics%29) of $a$ and $b$ as a fraction, $m$, then its decimal representation, $y$.

3a) If $y = x$ (to precision), then terminate

3b) If $y < x$, then let $a \leftarrow m$ and repeat step 2

3c) If $y > x$, then let $b \leftarrow m$ and repeat step 2

After terminating, $m$ now contains the fractional representation of $x$ with precision $p$.

(To address $x < 0$, let $x \leftarrow \lvert x\rvert$, perform the above and instead report $-m$.)